# How do I output the contents of a Set in Pascal?

Tags: freepascal

I'm working with simple sets in Pascal, and simply want to output the contents of a set. Everytime I run the code i get the following error message: 'project1.lpr(17,13) Error: Can't read or write variables of this type'.

here is my code:

```
  program Project1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  sysutils;

type TFriends = (Anne,Bob,Claire,Derek,Edgar,Francy);
type TFriendGroup = Set of TFriends;

Var set1,set2,set3,set4:TFriendGroup;    x:integer;

begin
set1:=[Anne,Bob,Claire];
set2:=[Claire,Derek];
set3:=[Derek,Edgar,Francy];
writeln(set1);
readln;
end.
```

Is there a special method/function to output sets?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>You can't directly display the set as a string because</del> there is no **type information** emitted for it. To do so, your set must be a **published** property of a class.

Once published in a class, you can use the unit **TypInfo** to display the set as a string, using the function **SetToString()**. **TypInfo** is the FPC unit which does all the compiler reflection things.

Short working example of what you try to do:

```
program Project1;
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
uses
  sysutils, typinfo;

type
  TFriends = (Anne,Bob,Claire,Derek,Edgar,Francy);
  TFriendGroup = Set of TFriends;

  TFoo = class
  private
    fFriends: TFriendGroup;
  published
    property Friends: TFriendGroup read fFriends write fFriends;
  end;

Var
  Foo: TFoo;
  FriendsAsString: string;
  Infs: PTypeInfo;

begin
  Foo := TFoo.Create;
  Foo.Friends := [Derek, Edgar, Francy];
  //
  Infs := TypeInfo(Foo.Friends);
  FriendsAsString := SetToString(Infs, LongInt(Foo.Friends), true);
  //
  Foo.Free;
  writeln(FriendsAsString);
  readln;
end.
```

This program outputs:

> [Derek,Edgar,Francy]

To go further:

- [official documentation about SetToString](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/typinfo/settostring.html)
- [this blog article](http://tondrej.blogspot.fr/2007/10/settostring-stringtoset.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guessed it wasn't so straight forward.

Answer (score 6):

Free Pascal allows write/writeln() of enums without explicit typinfo calls.

So

```
{$mode objfpc}  // or Delphi, For..in needs Object Pascal dialect iirc.
var Person :TFriends;

 for Person in Set1 do
    writeln(Person);
```

works fine.

Using [WriteStr](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/writestr.html) this can also be written to strings. (writestr functions like write/writestr but then to an string. Originally implemented for ISO/Mac dialects)